# Python UDP socket connect to external IP

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm trying to send and recieve messages using UDP and Python socket, to an external IP.

Here is my code:

```py
import socket

IP = ""
PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = b"Hello, World!"

sock_out = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_in = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock_in.bind("0.0.0.0", PORT)
sock_out.sendto(MESSAGE, (IP, PORT))
data, addr = sock_in.recvfrom(1024) # doesn't pass this line
print(data, addr)
```

The IP points to a server I made that returns every message sent to it (for testing).

I am wondering if this is the correct way of receiving UDP messages, since my program just hangs infinitely.

Comment: Well, I see no reason to say this is not the correct way to receive UDP messages.

I mean, you send a message and you expect an answer, so no doubt this is one way of implementing UDP based communication.

I suspect the problem resided in the server, though. Can you provide the code to us so we can check, please?

Comment: Server likely replies to the port it received data from. No need for `sock_in` if that is the case. Use `sock_out.recvfrom(1024)`.  You should show the server code as well.